# In EWS and C# how do I search for emails within custom folders?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use the EWS API to search for messages in all Exchange folders, by first getting a list of all folders and then doing a search query inside each of those folders. I used this method because a number of folders are created by the user themselves so won't be accessible WellKnownMailBoxName, plus there are sometimes subfolders. As such, I'm trying to use the Folder.Id.

The problem I am facing is that is that Folder.Id isn't doing anything - I simply get errors. I set up a variable as FolderNameA.Id but get nothing when using the code below. What is wrong? Is there another way in EWS and C# that I can search for emails within custom folders?

```
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);

//Get a list of all the folders
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep; 
FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root,
   searchFilter, view); 

//For every folder that is found
foreach (Folder myFolder in findFolderResults.Folders) {
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo findPrevious_searchfilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo
   (EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, messageSent.InReplyTo);

FindItemsResults<Item> findPrevious_searchResults = 
   service.FindItems(FolderNameA.ID, findPrevious_searchfilter,
   new ItemView(1));
```

... then I'll work on the output

Comment: Where is FolderNameA.ID coming from in ? your example you should be searching myFolder.Id from within you foreach loop

Comment: FolderNameA.ID was the issue. For some reason, it wasn't in the code above but it was in the code I had written - it must have been missed when I tried to format code for posting here. Nonetheless, I was assigning it FolderNameA.ID = myFolder.Id. It didn't work when I used that, but it did when I used: service.FindItems(myFolder.ID, findPrevious_searchfilter, new ItemView(1)); This seems to be either a typo or permissions issue but I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`FolderNameA.ID` was the issue. For some reason, it wasn't in the code above but it was in the code I had written - it must have been missed when I tried to format code for posting here. Nonetheless, I was assigning it `FolderNameA.ID = myFolder.Id`. It didn't work when I used that, but it did when I used: `service.FindItems(myFolder.ID, findPrevious_searchfilter, new ItemView(1));` This seems to be either a typo or permissions issue but I managed to fix it.